# Como asigno correctamente la url a un Attachment de Trix-Editor? Js,php,trix-editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest, wysiwyg

tengo un problema, yo tengo un formulario donde adentro hay un trix-editor, necesito que si el usuario quiere meter imágenes pueda hacerlo, según yo ya todo debería estar funcionando bien, aun me faltan hacer validaciones para el ingreso de datos, pero el codigo va algo asi:

```
<script>
    var editor = document.querySelector("editorTexto");
    var contenido = document.getElementById("contenidoNoticia");
    addEventListener("trix-attachment-add",(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var attachment = e.attachment;
        if(attachment.file){
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append('file',attachment.file);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST','/php/subirImagenes.php',true);
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(ev){
                var progreso = (ev.loaded * 100)/ev.total;
                console.log(`DL: ${ev.loaded} NEC: ${ev.total}`);
                attachment.setUploadProgress(progreso);
            }
            xhr.addEventListener("load",()=>{
                if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4){
                    console.log(xhr.responseText); //RESPONSETEXT SI DA LA DIRECCION
                    attachment.setAttributes({
                        url: xhr.responseText, //ESTOS DAN NULL
                        href : xhr.responseText //ESTOS DAN NULL
                    });
                }
            })
            console.log(xhr);
            xhr.send(form);
        }
    })
</script>
```

aquí el detalle es que la url de el attachment me esta dando null, aunque si esta regresando el responsiveText la dirección de la imagen, aqui esta el codigo php:

```
<?php
if($_FILES['file']){
    $tipos = ['jpg','png','gif','bmp','jpeg','webp','tiff'];
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if(in_array($extension,$tipos)){
        $dir2 = '../'.$direccion;
        $direccionImagen = $dir2.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $imgTemporal = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($imgTemporal,$direccionImagen)){
            echo 'http://localhost/'.$direccion.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Según la documentación de trix hay que agregar la url definitiva al attachment para que se pueda guardar, pero no logro la asignacion, me gustaria saber que opinan, que podria ser?
Mi objetivo final es que al darle submit al formulario se guarde ese trix-editor como un texto en mi base de datos y cuando yo lo recupere poder mostrar los datos conservando su formato e imágenes.También habia visto algo acerca de una función insertHtml o algo asi